# How to get the request path in a multiple store Magento setup to use in hreflang?

Tags: magento, seo

We would like to get request path to build dynamic URL for

```
    public function countryStoresAlternateLinks(){
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false);
    $countryAlternateLinks = '';
    foreach($stores as $store) {
    $countryAlternateLinks[] = '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . substr(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store->getId()), 0, 2) . (Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default', $store->getId()) != '' ?  "-" . Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default', $store->getId()) : '') .  '" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl(false) .'" />' . "\n";
    } 
    return $countryAlternateLinks;      }
```

Which gives the following output :

```
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://our_domain.com/magento/thee/losse-        bladthee/groene?SID=4d6ec9b2ada547a58c7b57dfb35b8d95&amp;___store=english" /> 
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" href="http://www.our_domain.nl/magento/thee/losse-bladthee/groene?___store=dutch" /> 
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="http://our_domain.com/magento/thee/losse-bladthee/groene?SID=4d6ec9b2ada547a58c7b57dfb35b8d95&amp;___store=nl_be" /> 
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="http://our_domain.com/magento/thee/losse-bladthee/groene?SID=4d6ec9b2ada547a58c7b57dfb35b8d95&amp;___store=fr_be" />
```

The function will print the base URL per store but the category path will not change per store view, it will remind in the same language.

****The question is – how can we specify the “href” to get the category path per store view / language?****

That is what we have got at the moment “href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl(false) .'”
Has anyone knows how we can achieve this?

---

thanks for the reply but not entirely what we are looking for. maybe i didn't explain very well in my first message, sorry.

In the end what we want to cal is the rewrite URL from the other shop, so for example:

instead of:

```
    www.domain.com/cat1/sub2/info-english.html
```

we want to call:

```
   www.domain.com/cat-fr/sub-fr/info-french.html
```

and this on the original english store, so we have nice clean links? Is there a way to achieve this in Magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
   ->setStoreId(each store id)
   ->load(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID);`
```

This would load each category according to store id. Get the url

Hope you got what was needed

:)